# Measure similarity between isomorphic graphs with different node labels

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, spectral-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am using graphs to represent some structured data. In my case, I have a time series of undirected unweighted graphs with the same topology (i.e. isomorphic graphs with same number of nodes and edges, and same connections). The only thing keeps changing over time are (some of) the node labels. In my case, the node labels are discrete (categorical labels). I want to use some kind of measurement to describe the similarity (or dis-similarity) between two given isomorphic graphs with different node labels. Note that this is fundamentally different from comparing two sequences in the sense that the local similarity at each node not only depends on the matchings of the node label, but also the matchings of the labels of the 1st, 2nd, ... nearest neighbors.

I am looking into graph kernels. In theory, there should be a significant speed-up given the graph topology is fixed, since one can precompute an original kernel and reuse it with different label distributions for different isomorphic graphs. However, I found that all common graph kernels assign the majority of the weight to topological features, which means I will always get very high similarity scores between two isomorphic graphs, even with completely different sets of node labels, which I would expect the similarity to be 0 in this case.

Can anyone suggest a good algorithm that can measure similarity between isomorphic graphs with different node labels? I have been looking for literature related to this, but could not find any. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Edit: note that there can be multiple isomorphisms. For example, as depicted below, $G_1$ and $G_2$ have different node labels at node 1, 3, 4, but they are completely identical, so they should have the highest similarity. This means that any similarity measurement that compares node labels by indices is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: You can maybe use a formula of the type : $\sum_{v \in V} \sum_{k = 1...n}|N_k(v)| \alpha_k \phi(v)$ where $\phi(v)$ is equal to $1$ if the labels do not match on $v$, $N_k(v)$ are the $k$-nearest neighbors, $\alpha_k$ is a decreasing function of $k$, and $n$ is fixed to make the computation tractable.

Comment: A better one could be $\sum_{v \in V} \sum_{k = 1...n}\sum_{v'\in V}s_k(v') \alpha_k \phi(v)$ where $s_k(v')$ is the number of $k$-paths from $v$ to $v'$.

Comment: @caduk Is it better if I use one-hot encoding for the node labels $\phi(v)$ instead of binary?

Comment: What would it change? To compute $\phi$, you just need to compare the labels, it does not matter how they are encoded.

Comment: @caduk I just realized that your $k$-shortest-path approach will fail when there are multiple isomorphisms. Right now you are comparing by the labels at each node index. Let's use a simple example: if we have a cycle topology of 1-2-3-4(-1). $G_1$ has the node labels of A-B-A-B(-A), $G_2$ has the labels of B-A-B-A(-B), obviously they should have the highest similarity because they are identical. But in your way of calculating similarity, this will return 0.

Comment: As I understand your problem,  your graphs always have an isomorphism and you only want to compute the similarity of graphs on exact isomorphisms (no costs on structural dissimilarity). The first step is probably to compute the automorphism group. If the group is relativey small, then you can compute the dissimilarity on all elements of the group (using for example the dissimilarity I proposed, which is a linear one). If it's bigger, then your problem reduce to optimizing hamming distance on a permutation group (assuming your dissimilarity is linear), and it is NP-hard

Comment: @caduk Unfortunately I have a huge network. I feel like the best way is probably to calculate the inner product of the label sequences on every pair of $k$-shortest-paths and sum them together. This way will guarantee automorphic graphs have exactly the same total similarity.

Comment: Your automorphism group may not be that big, even if your graph is big. And you can maybe do things with the structure of your automorphism group if you know it. For example, it is polynomial with a cyclic group : decompose your permutation in cycles. If the gcd of your cycles is one, then compute dissimilarity on all cycles, and sum these. We can easily adapt when gcd is not one. Do you know the structure of your automorphism group?

Comment: @caduk Yes I know. I have a periodic lattice structure with (only) translational invariance.

Comment: @caduk But considering there are many automorphism groups in my graph, it might be even slower to compute similarity for all automorphism groups than comparing every pair of $k$-shortest-paths.

Comment: If I understand right, you have a sort of automorphism group of a toroidal grid, with only the translational symmetry. You may look at the cyclic hamming distance for string (here on 2d), there are interesting results using fourier transform (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131994/algorithm-for-cyclic-n-string-hamming-distance-with-constant-sized-language), which would give a $n^2log(n)|\Sigma|$ complexity I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82715927.pdf) might be what you're looking for. You can phrase the algorithm as an eigenvalue problem. I remember implementing it, but it's kind of confusing until you look up what the different matrix products mean. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the paper suggestion. Yes the paper is confusing and I failed to understand how it is related to my question. Would you like to explain it in detail? Btw I have started a bounty.

Comment: The central idea is this: assign a score of local similarity to each node and edge in graph 1 to all nodes and edges in graph 2. Propagate the scores in graph 1 according to the edges in graph 2. If you do this iteratively, eventually the node with the most similar neighborhood in graph 1 will have the highest score for the corresponding node in graph 2. The point of the paper is proving this and rephrasing the question as an eigenvalue problem (Eq 5). The eigenvalue is the overall similarity score, while the elements of the eigenvector are the scores for pairs of nodes from graph 1 x graph 2.